# SqlQuery against unknown (at compile time) type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an application where I have a list of database queries to execute.

I know its possible to do something like:

```
var results = _db.Contacts.SqlQuery( sQuery );
```

and like:

```
var results = _db.Database.SqlQuery<Contacts>( sQuery );
```

But in my situation, I'm working only with metadata.  How can I do something like this:

```
string sBaseType = "Contacts";
var results = _db.Database.SqlQuery<sBaseType>( sQuery );
```

I had some success with `<object>`...it returned all the rows I expected it to, but its not in a very usable form.  Whats the best way to handle this variety of dynamic query?

Edit -- 
What I'm hoping to find, is some mechanism rather like this:

```
var results = _db.Database[sBaseType].SqlQuery( sQuery );
```

So that I can avoid a construction that looks like :

```
if (sBaseType == "Contacts") {
    var results = _db.Contacts.SqlQuery( sQuery );
} else if  (sBaseType == "Buildings") {
    var results = _db.Buildings.SqlQuery( sQuery );
} else if  (sBaseType == "Rooms") {
    var results = _db.Rooms.SqlQuery( sQuery );
} else if  (sBaseType == "Equipment") {
    var results = _db.Equipment.SqlQuery( sQuery );
}
```

I don't need anything particularly fancy...I just am hoping to save building up a 100+ element if-elseif block...

Comment: You can't do much with a generic result type with code. What do you do after that runs? Do you serialize it to JSON? If so, you should instead have a function that executes arbitrary SQL and builds the JSON for it directly without use of a view model. Such a function would iterate rows and columns and use a JSONWriter to build up the JSON output as it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to resolve my main issue ::

```
string sQuery = vo.objReport.sQuery;
object[] aParams = {} ;  //loaded through some other, related, process...

var tt = Type.GetType("MyProject.DAL." + vo.objReport.sBaseView);
var result =_db.Database.SqlQuery(tt, sQuery, aParams);
```

Given a bunch of metadata about the query to run, it is able to execute the query and return data in a usable format.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some sort of type resolution dictionary.

```
public abstract class MetadataQuery
{
  public abstract string Type { get; }
  public abstract string QueryString { get; }
}

public class ContactsQuery : MetadataQuery
{
  public override string Type { get { return "Contact"; } }
  public override string QueryString { get { return "select * from Contacts where is_deleted = 0"; } }
}
```

Write a query for each type.

Next, compile a list of types. Most IoC containers can do this for you. Using Ninject, you would do something like this. And dynamic types make this much more trivial.

```
kernel.Bind<MetadataQuery>().To<ContactsQuery>();
// keep doing this for all of your metadata queries.
```

Finally, when you're ready to actually use your query.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly IDbConnection db;
  private readonly IDictionary<string, MetadataQuery> queries;

  public MyClass(IDbConnection db, IEnumerable<MetadataQuery> queries)
  {
    this.db = db;
    this.queries = queries.ToDictionary(q => q.Type);
  }

  public IEnumerable<dynamic> ExecuteSQL(string type)
  {
    var query = queries[type];
    var result = db.Query(query.QueryString);
    return result;
  }
}
```

If you absolutely **must** have a non-dynamic type, you're going to need to look into [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx), but that won't be nearly as easy.

Comment: that looks less easy than just writing a huge if-elseif construct...see above for an edit on what I'm 'hoping' to find...

Comment: It's not meant to be 'easier'. It's meant to (a) solve your problem and (b) not violate the Open-Closed Principle. This solution accomplishes both of those things.

Comment: I appreciate that.  I'll admit that your answer is a bit above my head :D